# Python random variable not properly working

Tags: python, variables, random

Helloo

I'm trying to make a simple game where you have to choose either 1 or 2 and one of them is correct. I've used a simple random generator to choose either 1 or 2 as the correct answer.

```
def guess():

print("")
print("Select a number, 1 or 2")
print("")
from random import randint
ran = randint(1, 2)
nmr = input("")
if nmr == ran:
    print("That's correct!")
else:
    print("Wrong number")
```

Every time I answer it prints "Wrong number".

I've also tried printing the random number before answering but it still takes it as incorrect. Any idea what is wrong there?

Comment: `nmr = int(input(""))` is better in python 3

Comment: Yes: The result of `input()` is always a string, so it never compares equal to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing a `string` with an `int`. That always gives `False`.

```
ran = randint(1, 2)     #int
nmr = input("")         #str
```

So for it to work, either convert `ran` to `str` or `nmr` to `int`